# Find the algorithm to compute specific output from specific input

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

This problem is more on the mathematical side. I have given a list of 4-Byte UIDs in hex and a list of corresponding 2-Byte codes - let's call them hashes.

It looks like this:

```
7D04E214 --> 4A49
7D048DC3 --> A0E7
7D04DB2E --> 4191
...
```

I have something like 50 of these tuples, so I guess if I find an algorithm that computes the right hash for all of the UIDs, I can be pretty sure that is the correct one.

Here is my problem: I don't really know how to start. I am not a mathematician and have no experience with this kind of problems. I suspect some kind of bitwise algorithm. It looks like it could be CRC16 but I already falsified that. I don't think it's any popular algorithm. I also think (or rather hope) the algorithm is not too complicated.

I know that the generic problem of finding the function that computes a certain output from a certain input is undecidable. But assuming that the algorithm is a simple one, what possibilities do I have? Are there any tools available that could help me? Is there any read-up you can suggest for writing my own tool? I'm thinking about some kind of brute-force but how do I do this in a systematical way?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** Since there is some unclarity about my question: I really need to find the one algorithm that was used to create the hashes from the UIDs in the first place - or at least one that behaves the same way for all possible UIDs (i.e. 4-Byte numbers). Since it was pointed out that there is an infinite number of possible functions, I guess I have to find the simplest ones and test them against more UID values. As I said, I'm actually assuming that the algorithm is simple and not full of obscure keys. If I'm wrong, I'm doomed as you noted. But if not, maybe I have a chance with trial-and-error.

Comment: Probably belongs on [one of](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) [the](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) [other](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) [sites](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Given 50 tuples, find an algorithm that successfully predicts the mapping for a kew key: no chance. Given 50 tuples, find an algorithm that successfully maps all keys: trivial. Given 50 tuples, find an algorithm that successfully maps all keys without actually storing the map: non-trivial to perform automatically. Also, not often useful.

Comment: A slightly more explicit version of @JanDvorak's answer: given that it's only 50 pairs and you weren't given the hashing algorithm then the easiest solution is to just create a map (e.g. Java's `HashMap` or Python's `dict`) where the key is the original string and the value (obtained from entering the key) is the desired hash. 50 is a small number for a computer so it isn't worth your time to try to reverse engineer the hashing algorithm (a difficult to practically impossible task depending on the hashing algorithm used).

Comment: You can experiment using genetic programming and a set of pre-defined functions (<, >, +, -, xor, *, /, %, whatever else that might be needed). The resulting formula will very likely be huge, which can be simplified, and (more likely) might not represent the actual unknown function. You would need a much larger labeled data to have any confidence on the resulting formula from that approach.

Comment: For example, the original function might be an AES with an unknown key.

Comment: That's why I have to suppose that the algorithm is simple (and not a real hash). I know my chances are small but I want to try at least. A dictionary will not be a solution because I need to find the right function which is also working for UIDs I don't have on the list. I will have a look at genetic programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have commented/answered, you have an ill-posed problem together with very little known information of the unknown function (well, it is unknown after all :). While you could try guessing a function by means of Genetic Programming, you cannot expect to have any confidence that it actually represents the unknown function -- not with only 50 inputs `->` outputs.

But, as a dummy experiment, I toyed with Genetic Programming and it found the following program for your 3 examples given:

```
def guess(a, key=0xbeef): # The parameter 'a' is an input value.
    temp = (a % (-14)) << 3
    if temp == 0:
        temp = -4
    temp = ((a ^ (-2 * key)) - temp) >> 2
    res = (temp + a + (a % (-15))) % key
    return res
```

Which gives the following results:

```
Input      Output (guess)   Actual output    Diff
0x7d04e214 0x4a49           0x4a49           0
0x7d048dc3 0xa0e7           0xa0e7           0
0x7d04db2e 0x4191           0x4191           0
```

So the produced program has a total error of 0 units for these inputs, thus the function is correct for the given examples, but that means nothing. It took a couple of runs, thousands of generations, etc, to generate a program that gave no error for the examples. Now, the immediate problem to be noticed here is that I assumed the unknown function takes a `key` parameter together with the input -- which might or not be the case. Furthermore, I simply guessed the key could be `0xbeef` mostly because it is a nice hex value. The consequence of these decisions is that the program will try to produce a program to accommodate for these choices, which could be totally incorrect in relation to what the unknown function does. What this means is that you will need to somehow make this unknown function be a little more known than it is right now in order to expect any relevant results.

Comment: I find this result really impressive, even if it does not work with the rest of the UIDs, as you expected. Could you elaborate on how you did the genetic programming part? I'm a total novice on this field so some help would be great. If I could find one function for all of the values, that would be an impressive result to show my boss that the problem is not solvable that way.

Comment: It started by generating `n` random programs that were restricted to use some basic functions: constant number, parameter access, addition, subtraction, multiplication, modulus, xor, if then else, and some others that are mostly shortcuts (such as specifics shift left/right). Then each of these programs are evaluated according to the known inputs `->` outputs. The `k` best programs (those that produce output closer to the known ones) are kept and the rest is either completely mutated or a crossover operator is applied between two programs. This is repeated for a number `g` of generations.

Comment: That will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try to clarify what especially you are trying to achieve.

If you only want to be able to map something like 50 FIXED input values to some ohter 50 FIXED output values, as already suggested creating some kind of mapping table from input to output values should suffice.

If on the other hand given some 50 input values and their corresponding 50 output values and want to be able to correctly PREDICT the corresponding output value for ANY other input value at least from a mathematical standpoint your problem is unsolvable as given ANY fixed number of input to output value mappings there still is in INFINITE number of functions that map ALL of the input values seen so far to exactly the same output values seen so far and still calculating another result for any value not seen so far.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an impossible quest unless you can either find out more information or assemble a mapping of all possible inputs and their outputs so you can experiment exhaustively.